# Electrodynamics using exterior calculus

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations

Can anyone suggest resource for full course of electrodynamics using exterior calculus?

Comment: Burke, Applied differential geometry, http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Differential-Geometry-William-Burke/dp/0521269296